# Data is not inserting into mysql database through android application

Tags: java, android, mysql, android-asynctask

I am new to android , When I am trying to insert the data from 
my android app to localhost MySQL database,App is terminating  automatically. 
MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity

{

EditText ET_id,ET_FIRSTPLACE,ET_SECONDPLACE,ET_DISTANCE,ET_TIME2REACH,ET_FARE;
Button BT_SUBMIT;
String id,firstplace,secondplace,distance,time2reach,fare;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)

{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ET_id=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.id);
    ET_FIRSTPLACE=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.firstplace);
    ET_SECONDPLACE=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.secondplace);
    ET_DISTANCE=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.distance);
    ET_TIME2REACH=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.time2reach);
    ET_FARE=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.fare);
    BT_SUBMIT=(Button)findViewById(R.id.submit);

}

public  void submit(View view)


{
    id=ET_id.getText().toString();
    firstplace=ET_FIRSTPLACE.getText().toString();
    secondplace=ET_SECONDPLACE.getText().toString();
    distance =ET_DISTANCE.getText().toString();
    time2reach=ET_TIME2REACH.getText().toString();
    fare=ET_FARE.getText().toString();

     String method="submit";

    BackgroundTask backgroundTask= new BackgroundTask(this);
    backgroundTask.execute(method,id,firstplace,secondplace,distance,time2reach,fare);
   finish();
 }
}
```

BackgroundTask.java

```
/**
 * Created by Sumedh on 29/08/2015.
 */
public class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask <String,Void,String> {

Context ctx;

BackgroundTask(Context ctx) {

    this.ctx = ctx;

}

protected String doInBackground(String... params)


{
    String reg_url = "http://10.0.3.2/busspotter/insert.php";

        String method=params[0];
        String id =params[1];
        String firstplace =params[2];
        String secondplace =params[3];
        String distance =params[4];
        String time2reach =params[5];
        String fare =params[6];
if(method.equals("submit")) {
try {
    URL url = new URL(reg_url);
HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();  
    httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
    //httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);

    OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
    BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream,"UTF-8"));

    String data = URLEncoder.encode("id","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(id,"UTF-8")+"&"+
            URLEncoder.encode("firstplace","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(firstplace,"UTF-8")+"&"+
            URLEncoder.encode("secondplace","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(secondplace,"UTF-8")+"&"+
            URLEncoder.encode("distance","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(distance,"UTF-8")+"&"+
            URLEncoder.encode("time2reach","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(time2reach,"UTF-8")+"&"+
            URLEncoder.encode("fare","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(fare,"UTF-8");
    bufferedWriter.write(data);
    bufferedWriter.flush();
    bufferedWriter.close();
    outputStream.close();
    InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
    inputStream.close();
    httpURLConnection.disconnect();
    return "Inserted Succesfully...";
 } catch (MalformedInputException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();

 } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();

 }
}
return null;

 }

protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        if (result.equals("Inserted Succesfully...")) {
            Toast.makeText(ctx, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    }
}
```

Here is my logCat-

```
08-30 04:57:49.368  17491-17491/? D/dalvikvm﹕ Late-enabling CheckJNI
08-30 04:57:49.392  17491-17497/? E/jdwp﹕ Failed sending reply to debugger:Broken pipe
08-30 04:57:49.392  17491-17497/? D/dalvikvm﹕ Debugger has detached; object       registry had 1 entries
08-30 04:57:49.596  17491-17491/? D/libEGL﹕ loaded/system/lib/egl/libEGL_genymotion.so
08-30 04:57:49.600  17491-17491/? D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb943bea0, tid 17491
08-30 04:57:49.624  17491-17491/? D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_genymotion.so
08-30 04:57:49.624  17491-17491/? D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_genymotion.so
08-30 04:57:49.700  17491-17491/? W/EGL_genymotion﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
08-30 04:57:49.704  17491-17491/? E/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from GradienCache
08-30 04:57:49.708  17491-17491/? E/OpenGLRenderer﹕ MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 16384
08-30 04:57:49.716  17491-17491/? E/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from Caches::initConstraints()
08-30 04:57:49.724  17491-17491/? E/OpenGLRenderer﹕ MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 16384
08-30 04:57:49.728  17491-17491/? D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
08-30 04:57:59.983  17491-17506/com.example.sumedh.busspotterinsert D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 185K, 9% free 3043K/3316K, paused 5ms, total 5ms
08-30 04:57:59.987  17491-17506/com.example.sumedh.busspotterinsert W/System.err﹕ java.net.SocketException: socket failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
08-30 04:57:59.987  17491-17506/com.example.sumedh.busspotterinsert W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.IoBridge.socket(IoBridge.java:576)
08-30 04:57:59.987  17491-17506/com.example.sumedh.busspotterinsert W/System.err﹕ at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.create(PlainSocketImpl.java:201)
08-30 04:57:59.987  17491-17506/com.example.sumedh.busspotterinsert W/System.err﹕ at java.net.Socket.checkOpenAndCreate(Socket.java:664)
08-30 04:57:59.987  17491-17506/com.example.sumedh.busspotterinsert W/System.err﹕ at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:808)
08-30 04:57:59.987  17491-17506/com.example.sumedh.busspotterinsert W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.java:131)
08-30 04:57:59.987  17491-17506/com.example.sumedh.busspotterinsert W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:101)
08-30 04:57:59.987  17491-17506/com.example.sumedh.busspotterinsert W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:294)
08-30 04:57:59.987  17491-17506/com.example.sumedh.busspotterinsert W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:255)
08-30 04:57:59.987  17491-17506/com.example.sumedh.busspotterinsert W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:206)
08-30 04:57:59.987  17491-17506/com.example.sumedh.busspotterinsert W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:345)
08-30 04:57:59.991  17491-17506/com.example.sumedh.busspotterinsert W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:89)
08-30 04:57:59.991  17491-17506/com.example.sumedh.busspotterinsert W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:197)
08-30 04:57:59.991  17491-17506/com.example.sumedh.busspotterinsert W/System.err﹕ at com.example.sumedh.busspotterinsert.BackgroundTask.doInBackground(BackgroundTask.java:49)
08-30 04:57:59.991  17491-17506/com.example.sumedh.busspotterinsert W/System.err﹕ at com.example.sumedh.busspotterinsert.BackgroundTask.doInBackground(BackgroundTask.java:18)
08-30 04:57:59.991  17491-17506/com.example.sumedh.busspotterinsert W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
08-30 04:57:59.991  17491-17506/com.example.sumedh.busspotterinsert W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
08-30 04:57:59.991  17491-17506/com.example.sumedh.busspotterinsert W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
08-30 04:57:59.991  17491-17506/com.example.sumedh.busspotterinsert W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
08-30 04:57:59.991  17491-17506/com.example.sumedh.busspotterinsert W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
08-30 04:57:59.991  17491-17506/com.example.sumedh.busspotterinsert W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
08-30 04:57:59.991  17491-17506/com.example.sumedh.busspotterinsert W/System.err﹕ Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: socket failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
08-30 04:57:59.991  17491-17506/com.example.sumedh.busspotterinsert W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.Posix.socket(Native Method)
08-30 04:57:59.991  17491-17506/com.example.sumedh.busspotterinsert W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.socket(BlockGuardOs.java:181)
08-30 04:57:59.991  17491-17506/com.example.sumedh.busspotterinsert W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.IoBridge.socket(IoBridge.java:561)
08-30 04:57:59.991  17491-17506/com.example.sumedh.busspotterinsert W/System.err﹕ ... 19 more
08-30 04:58:00.071  17491-17491/com.example.sumedh.busspotterinsert D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
08-30 04:58:00.071  1749117491/com.example.sumedh.busspotterinsertW/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa4cf2b20)
08-30 04:58:00.071  17491-17491/com.example.sumedh.busspotterinsert E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.sumedh.busspotterinsert, PID: 17491
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.example.sumedh.busspotterinsert.BackgroundTask.onPostExecute(BackgroundTask.java:85)
        at com.example.sumedh.busspotterinsert.BackgroundTask.onPostExecute(BackgroundTask.java:18)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Is your android connected to the wifi when msking the http request ? As you seem to make the request on a private lan address.

Answer (score 0):

Your

```
protected String doInBackground(String... params)
```

method returns null, and your onPostExecute(String result) try to read value from NULL object.

try to add this

```
if (result != null && result.equals("Inserted Succesfully...")) {
        Toast.makeText(ctx, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    } else Toast.makeText(ctx, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: I tried Your solution Sir but  not working ,app is Showing "something went wrong and getting terminated.